# Can not find one or more component. Please reinstall the application Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

When I am going to open the open my SQL Server and Visual Studio 2015, It's showing

> Can not find one or more component. Please reinstall the application Visual Studio 2015.

What should I do now? I have already reinstalled my application Visual Studio 2015. But nothing has changed. So can anyone please relief me form this error?

Comment: You'll need to work out which component it is missing. Can you find any relevant logs? When you say opening SQL Server do you mean opening SQL Server management studio or do you mean actually starting the SQL server service? Does the service start? And starting Visual Studio fails with the same error? Can you try Visual Studio 2017 or 2019?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. No I dont find any relevant log here . The error showing while opening Sql Server Management Studio .Its same while starting visual studio 2015. I didn't  try vs 2017 or 2019 caz I have to work with vs 2015. My project are there. Please give me solution.

Comment: You can download [the latest SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and that should work with SQL Server 2015 fine and hopefully not conflict with your Visual Studio installation, so then you'll just have to fix SQL Server. But I think you will need to find out which component it cannot find, we can't guess that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: You can refer to the similar problem [How to fix visual studio error “cannot find one or more components .Please re-install the application” in windows 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863015/11507778). Please try to delete keys in register.